# Same Test Case, Different Parameter Value

Tags: tsqlt

As per reading the discussion in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885513/any-solutions-to-getting-nunit-style-testcase-functionality-in-tsqlt/47888728#47888728), I already have an idea how to call same test case with different parameter value.  However, when I look at tSQLt.TestResult table, I only have the record of the last run.  Sample pseudo code below represent the scenario.

EXEC tSQLt.Run 'Main_SP';

--Main SP Pseudocode

Create Proc Main_SP

Declare @param

Select @param = 1

exec MyTestCase @param

Select @param = 2

exec MyTestCase @param

Select @param = 3

exec MyTestCase @param

Is there a way I can still see the complete history in tSQLt.TestResult of the same test case for other parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I think what the answer you linked to describes the following:

step1. create a stored procedure that is not a test that the tSQLt test runner will run but will allow you to pass in parameters.
step2. create one or more specific test cases that are actual tsqlt tests but have different names.

This will give you the advantage of being able to name each test for a specific scenario, but will remove the need to write repeated test code for each case.

```
exec tSQLt.NewTestClass 'MyTestClass';
go;
-- step1: notice this test does not start with the keyword test so 
-- will not be executed by the test runner
create procedure [MyTestClass].[GenericTestScenario]
@param int
as
begin 
  -- write you generic test logic and then the assert
  declare @result int = dbo.yourFunctionUnderTest(@param);
  exec tSQLt.AssertEquals(@param, @result);
end 
go
-- step 2 (another test case)
create procedure [MyTestClass].[test Specific Scenario 1]
as
begin
  declare @param = 1;
  exec MyTestClass.GenericTestScenario @param
end
go
-- step 2 (first test case)
create procedure [MyTestClass].[test Specific Scenario 2]
as
begin
  declare @param = 2;
  exec MyTestClass.GenericTestScenario @param
end
go

tSQLt.run 'MyTestClass'
go
```